# mathjax in new windows

Tags: html, mathjax, new-window

I've got a test code for playing with MathJax, it is to show some numbered and referable math equations, and a button which is aimed to open a new windows in the browser with the same math content ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax Equation References</title>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2012-2013 The MathJax Consortium -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
         MathJax.Hub.Config({
           jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
           extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
           tex2jax: {
             inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]],
             displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
           },
           TeX: {
               extensions: ["AMSmath.js"],
               equationNumbers: {  autoNumber: "AMS"  }  //automatic eqn numbering !!!
           }
         });
   </script>

<script type="text/javascript" async  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
In equation \eqref{eq:sample}, we find the value of an
interesting integral:

\begin{equation}
  \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}\,dx = \frac{\pi^4}{15}
  \label{eq:sample}
\end{equation}
<h1>A test of Equation References</h1>

<hr>
Here is a labeled equation:

\begin{equation}x+1\over\sqrt{1-x^2}\label{ref1}\end{equation}
with a reference to ref1: \ref{ref1},
and another numbered one with no label:
$$x+1\over\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
This one uses \nonumber:
$$x+1\over\sqrt{1-x^2}\nonumber$$
<hr>
Here's one using the equation environment:
\begin{equation}
x+1\over\sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{equation}
and one with equation* environment:
\begin{equation*}
x+1\over\sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{equation*}
<br><br><br>
<hr>
</div>


 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<br><br><br>
<script>
var contents=document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
function myFunction(){
    var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,width=400,height=400");
    myWindow.document.write('  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>MathJax Equation References</title><!-- Copyright (c) 2012-203 The MathJax Consortium --><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">         MathJax.Hub.Config({           jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],           extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],           tex2jax: {             inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]],             displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[","\\]"] ],             processEscapes: true,             processEnvironments: true           },           TeX: {               extensions: ["AMSmath.js"],               equationNumbers: {  autoNumber: "AMS"  }  //automatic eqn numbering !!!           }         });   </scr'+'ipt><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></scr'+'ipt></head><body>'+contents+'</div><br><br><br></body></html>');
    setTimeout(function(){ myWindow.stop(); }, 15000);  // assures that the windows stop loading after at most 15s
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

but the math content in the new page is not rendered on page-load, any clue on how to fix it? The `<head>` tag in both the main and the new windows are the same ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put the entire MathJax configuration in a single line but left a comment inside it:

`//automatic eqn numbering !!!           }         });   </scr'+'ipt>`

This leads to the final `}});` being commented out which in turn breaks the configuration (it's now invalid JavaScript).

Just remove `//automatic eqn numbering !!!`

If you open the developer console, you will find an error message which would have been a good starting point for debugging.